# Join two tables in mssql with column int and varchar having comma seperated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as tblemployee and tbllead . My issue is in tblemployee i have column **id** as a integer value  and tbllead column **leademployees** having varchar with comma seperated value.

So when I am joining this two table i am facing problem.
**select * from tblemployee as e join tbllead as l
on e.id=l.LeadEmployees**

Getting:- Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

[image: MY Table Structure]

My desired result should have all the columns values except 4.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Bad Habit :Don't design table column in above mentioned way

Comment: Thats obnoxious to point something like that out.  He could be taking over someone else's work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general solution which should work on any standard database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID
FROM tblemployee t1
INNER JOIN tbllead t2
    ON ',' + t2.leademployees + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.ID) + ',%'
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

This query uses a trick I first saw being used by @CL , which can best be explained by showing some data.  The first row of `tbllead` has this data:

```
1,2,6,7
```

The comparison for the inner numbers and outer numbers is different, due to the presence/abseence of one of the commas on either side.  But if we concantenate commas around this string, we get the following:

```
,1,2,6,7,
```

Now, we can just compare every `ID` from the `tblemployee` table, surrounded by commas, against the list of employees on every record.  That is, compare `,1,` `,2,` etc.

Here is a demo for SQL Server:

### Demo

If you are using MySQL, the above query would change slightly.  Also, there would be an even tighter option in MySQL using `FIND_IN_SET`.  But the answer I gave is more useful in my view, because it can easily be applied regardless of the database.